# How to get multiple values from UITableview cell using accessory view checkmark?

Tags: iphone

Ha ii every body,i am using accessory view checkmark for selection multiple values from a UITableview cell,i put the this code in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
NSArray* toReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: indexPath, self.selectedIndexPath, nil];
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

        BOOL selected = [[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] boolValue];
        [appDelegate.notesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!selected]];

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }

    else {

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    }
```

My need is when the user select the multiple values from the uitableview cell,it has to be stored in a array and pass the array to the button click.i want these array to share in googledoc.How to get that array of multiple values from the UITbleViewCell.what code did i put it in button click?and i want to pass that value for share.if any sample code is there for reference it would be a great help for me.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableArray *selected_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) {
        if (selected[i]) [selected_items addObject:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];


            UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {

                [m_owner uploadString:@""];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }


        }    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get values from a tableview only checkmark is the accessory view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463013/how-to-get-values-from-a-tableview-only-checkmark-is-the-accessory-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your asking is how to do a multiple select table view? - If so, this should help:

In your .h

```
BOOL selected[/* max number of cells */];
```

When the user selects a cell

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        selected[row] = NO;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        selected[row] = YES;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

On the button click

```
- (void)buttonClick {
    // pass the boolean array into the next controller, or just pass the items you need.
    // for example:


    for (int i = 0; i<[items count]; i++) {
        if (selected[i]) [m_owner uploadString:[items objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
```

See [here](http://github.com/lexy0202/MultiSelect) for a demonstration project I've made on multiple select.

Comment: thnks for the reply.this is my code in the button click UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {
              
                [m_owner uploadString:path];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
            

        }    i want to upld the selected index to gdoc,i.e. try will be path

Comment: i want to pass string value continuing this selced index array, [m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the values];

Comment: items is your array you are displaying in the tableview yes

Comment: ,thanks for your kind response,btw i have doubt that i want to upload  string of multiple values through this code [m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the values];what will i want to put in the above code for uploading to GDoc?Please see my edited question,plesw chi if its right or not.Thnks

Comment: do you want a URL query string?

Comment: sir ,my need is to pass the string to  [m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the values];this code,if i pass a single value in a textfield to this ,it successfully upload,but i want to get multiple Value from the tbleview as an array and pas it as a string in the Above code.

Comment: if i write  [m_owner uploadString:textField.text];it uploads the TExtfield value to the GDocs.i got successful in that section,but i want multiple value to pass as i said earlier.Thnks sir.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5753/discussion-between-icoder-and-alex-coplan)

Comment: sir i thnk half of the work done,i selected two rows from the UITableview cell and upload ,in my GDoc only one row is uploaded.- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{    NSMutableArray *selected_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) {
        UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
        if (uploadview != nil)
        {
         if (selected[i]) [m_owner uploadString:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  
            }
            
        }    
} any error in my code ?Thnk very much

Comment: ver very unlucky,server down for Github.what a faith...thanks for your kind response.

Comment: Alex, I believe your MultiSelect project is broken.  If you select all cells and then scroll up all the check marks disappear.

Comment: @ruggershawn You're absolutely right - I've fixed it and pushed the change, sorry about that - I wasn't setting the cells to the stored boolean values so if the cells were re-drawn (because they went off the screen) they would be re-drawn with no checkmark! thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your table. If Not to big, you can use an `int` to check if a row is selected or not each bit of the integer will represent the state (selected or not) of the table view rows